# All of my rigify rigs eventually vanish from their files

Tags: rigging, rigify

I'm currently working on a project that requires several different character models. I have every character in separate files. The rigs will work, and the controls will be there for a while, but eventually if I need to come back to a model after a while, the rig will just be gone. Everything is still there in the outliner, I checked and nothing is hidden, I checked the bone layers. When I open files with rig animation that this has happened to, the animation is also gone. There are no keyframes, and if I check the weight painting mode the mesh has no information, and has no vertex groups or bones I can weight paint for. This happens with EVERY FILE. The metarig is still present in the file, and I can generate a rig based on it again, but I don't want to have to redo the weight paints and reparent every time this happens.

I have at least 15 different character rigs, and after x amount of time it happens to every single one, so I have to get all the animations done asap and exported so they can be used. I have the rigs exported, but I have no clue how to properly reimport them into blender, in case this is a way for me to continue making changes/new animations.

[image: Outliner]

Edit: I tried reparenting it to a new rig based on the metarig that stayed in the file, and with automatic weight painting it does this for some reason: [image: Automatic weight paints]

If I parent it with empty weights it's fine, but I really do not want to have to start from scratch with weight paints every time this happens.

Comment: Your second image shows that you've opened your Blend file created in Blender 3 or above in an earlier version of Blender. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hiw3gEZCgwo) video explains the reason and shows how to get round the problem. I've no idea whether this is the reason for your other problems too, but backwards compatibility isn't guaranteed with Blend files!

Comment: That would be it! The mac at my work apparently has been running 2.8 and I had no idea, my laptop has 3.0 so I've had to occasionally transfer files between them when I work from home, so I'm updating the mac now. Hopefully it will fix the issue with the rigs randomly vanishing too. Thanks!

Comment: Fingers crossed that it cures your problems!

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that was not the solution. Already several of the rigs that I made just today suddenly broke and the controls have vanished entirely from them. I had just closed them, and then reopened them just to see each one now has no control rig, but everything still in the outliner. I really have no clue why it keeps doing this.